# Fluent NHibernate - Use Stored Proc for Delete

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We've implemented Fluent NHibernate, but we have a need to execute a stored proc when deleting a row for a couple of tables.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without creating a command object and enlisting it with the session's transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `SqlDelete(sprocName)` call in your mapping class constructor.